# Is there a function or equation that can trace the trajectory of a space rocket's motion on the three coordinate axes $(x ,y ,z)$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, rocket-science

To be honest I'm working on a project at the university which is a simulation of launching a rocket into space The problem here is that this simulation needs to be realistic enough for my programming skills It is difficult to predict the trajectory of the missile’s movement by measuring the physical forces affecting it and applying them programmatically. Therefore, could there be an equation that tracks the rocket's movement, just as there are functions that follow the movement of the rockets? I looked in the resources available to me and didn't find anything

Or can I consider the rocket as a projectile with an initial velocity and apply the equations of the missile trajectory?

Comment: My gut feeling is that simulation is the best you can do. But you aslo need to specify what assumptions you can operate under. Things like aerodynamics, fuel burn (mass loss), the shape of gravity etc would affect the results.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no general trajectory of a rocket. Calculating the forces programmatically is probably your best bet. I would recommend first trying this in 2D and once you get that working maybe proceed to 3D since working with 3D angles can be a bit tricky.

Comment: thanks @JAlex I considered all of things you mentioned it but the doctor asked for the curved motion path of the rocket and how the rocket change his path by changing those parameters you mentioned

Comment: thanks @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I know that but this thing is a requirement in the project